# Solving an exponential recurrence relation

Tags: inequality, recurrence-relations

Let $f(t)$ be a sequence s.t. $e^{f(t)}\geq e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n}+e^{\frac{2}{n}f(t-1)}$ where $f(0)=e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n}, t\in \mathbb{N}, t\geq 1$. I am trying to find a lower bound on $f(t)$ as a function of $n,t$. So I was trying to think of this as a recurrence inequality but am not sure how to solve an exponential recurrence relation because I'm used to linear recurrence relations. Any ideas?

If we look at a few terms, it looks as follows:

\begin{align*}
e^{f(t)} &\geq e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n} + e^{\frac{2}{n}f(t-1)} \\
&= e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n} + \left( e^{f(t-1)} \right)^\frac{2}{n} \\
&\geq e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n} + \left( e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n} + e^{\frac{2}{n}f(t-2)} \right)^{\frac{2}{n}}\\ 
&\geq \cdots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

For any $t$, the exponential being positive on $\mathbb{R}$,
$$ e^{f(t)} \geq e^{\frac{2}{n}\ln(n)} + e^{\frac{2}{n}f(t-1)} \geq e^{\frac{2}{n}\ln(n)} $$
and taking the logarithm of the last inequality we have
$$ f(t) \geq \frac{2}{n}\ln(n). $$

Comment: Looking for a better bound than that because that's trivial.

Comment: Have you got any extra information about $f$ like continuity or existence of limit as $|t| \longrightarrow + \infty$ ?

Comment: Added details now. $t\in \mathbb{N}, t\geq 1$. So I am thinking of $f(t)$ as a sequence as $t$ changes and not as a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is some confusion from using $n$ and $t\in \mathbb{N}.$ So, let $n^{2/n} = c.$ Now, let $g(t) = \exp(f(t)),$ so we have:

$$g(t) \geq c + g(t-1)^{2/n}\geq c + (c+ g(t-2)^{2/n})^{2/n}\sim c + c^{2/n} (1+ \frac2n \frac{g(t-2)^{2/n}}{c}) $$ for $n$ large. This shows that the trivial bound given by *blamethelag* is close to sharp.

Comment: I see, may I know why $(1+g(t-2)^{2/n})^{2/n} \sim (1+\frac{2}{n}g(t-2)^{2/n})$ for large $n$?